# Why are bundles used as opposed to standard Objects?

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, bundle, android-lifecycle

In android, why are bundles, used as opposed to classes? Surely this isn't very efficient. I find it also makes things really messy as you have to use loads of static keys from classes, that are often not well scoped. Not very intuitive either.

I'm sure generics can be used so you don't have to blindly cast returned Objects.

Answer (score 3):

A `Bundle` is `Parcelable`. `Parcelable` objects are designed to be passed across process boundaries. So, you will see `Bundle` and other `Parcelable` objects used a lot where inter-process communication (IPC) is involved, including:

- `Intent` extras, as we use IPC every time we start an activity, start a service, etc.
- the saved instance state, as that state is held in a core OS process in case our own process gets terminated

Arbitrary objects cannot be passed across process boundaries.

---

Also, a `Bundle` is a framework class. All apps, plus the core OS, work off of the same definition. As as result, a `Bundle` can be passed from one app to another, and both apps can use the contents of the `Bundle` (assuming its contents are themselves simple primitives or are based on other shared class definitions).

Even if you make your own class `Parcelable`, you may run into problems when other apps try to access that object, since they will not have your class definition.

---

For within your own app — particularly if you use the single-activity UI approach — the only time you need to work with a `Bundle` is for the saved instance state. If you are using `ViewModel` or similar ways of handling configuration changes, you do not need to store very much in the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: For your point about other apps using your Bundle, they'd still have to access your class to find the appropriate keys for the bundle. It's like getting data as buffer from another app, you still need some form of protocol to actually read it.

Comment: @Tobiq: "they'd still have to access your class to find the appropriate keys for the bundle" -- not really. Keys are strings. They can be typed in by programmers. "It's like getting data as buffer from another app, you still need some form of protocol to actually read it" -- correct. However, `Bundle` is like JSON, where you do not need a protocol-specific class to read it. A custom `Parcelable`, on the other hand, cannot be used without the protocol-specific class.

Comment: "you still need some form of protocol to actually [*understand*] it"

Comment: You end up having to consult documentation -- if you're lucky enough to have any provided -- for the most trivial retrieval of data.

Comment: @Tobiq: If this is completely within one project (e.g., saved instance state), you have equal need for documentation with a custom-class approach. If this is across apps, not only do you need that documentation, but you would need the actual class, and that tends to be a be a bigger problem. Also note that if you are using Kotlin, you can create private extension functions on `Bundle` to give you the feel of having a custom class.